# How to find TextView with ID when creating ID's with View.GenerateViewId

Tags: android, textview, findviewbyid

I'm creating X amount of TextViews dynamically and giving them ID's with View.generateViewId().

```
 TextView textView = new TextView(this);
  textView.setText("_");
  ...
  ...  
  int id = View.generateViewId();
  textView.setId(id);
```

And I get some IDs generated e.g 1-5, depending on the number of TextViews. But after searching different forums and the official android site I can't figure out how to access these ID's.

How do I target lets say the TextView with ID = 1 if I want to setText() in that one? Tried some different things like using findViewById and R-class but doesn't seem to work.

Appreciate any direct help or links that are relevant, thanks.

Comment: we should keep the ids in some map (name->GENERATED ID) and use the map when needed please

Comment: Agree with Hovanes's suggestion, but consider using Recyclerview if you are generating an indeterminate amount of views dynamically

Comment: @HovanesMosoyan  thanks I've tried that. But I still can't figure out how to use it. I can't do "findViewById(1)". How do I write code that says I want the TextView with  the generated ID of 1?

Comment: @Shmuel thanks I've tried that. But I still can't figure out how to use it. I can't do "findViewById(1)". How do I write code that says I want the TextView with  the generated ID of 1?

Comment: You can't use id of 1, what is it you are trying to accomplish here? More context would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. declare the map:

   ```
   public static final Map<String, Integer> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   ```
2. keep a track of items:

   ```
   int id = View.generateViewId();
   textView.setId(id);
   ITEM_MAP.put("key1", id);

   int id2 = View.generateViewId();
   textView.setId(id2);
   ITEM_MAP.put("key2", id2);
   ```

3.and then when needed:

```
    int id = ITEM_MAP.get("key?X"); 
    TextView textView = findViewById(id);
```

Good luck )

Comment: Thanks you very much, now I understand how I could solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going for a map, I'd suggest the same as @Hovanes Mosoyan's Answer but, rather than using strings as keys, use the id's as keys and then the value would be the textviews.

```
private Map<Int, TextView> textViewMap = HashMap();
...
// Add a textview to the map:
textViewMap.put(id, textView);
...
// Retrieve a textview from the map:
textViewMap.get(id);
```

But, this may have let downs since view id's are not required to be unique and you might get the wrong view. Also, if the id is repeated, it will be overwritten using the map, hence the last view with the same id will be taken.

## **So Here is a better way to do it**

Use tags. View's have their own tags which are strings. Now, as default, a view's tag is empty. This means, we can manipulate it the way we want, and for you, to use it as a unique identifier. Now, the problem is how do we generate a unique id? That's easy, use the current time, as time will never repeat itself.

```
...
int id = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Use intelli-sense, this might not be the right name of the function
textView.setTag("" + id);
...
// Retrieve the view using the tag
TextView textView = findViewWithTag("" + id);
...
```

Comment: great solution man